# Column counts are larger than 1996099046, unable to calculate percentiles

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

while I am running TableHistograms getting below message:

NodeTool TableHistograms keyspace TableName

```
Column counts are larger than 1996099046, unable to calculate percentiles

Percentile  SSTables     Write Latency      Read Latency    Partition Size        Cell Count
                              (micros)          (micros)           (bytes)
50%             0.00              0.00              0.00         268650950               NaN
75%             0.00              0.00              0.00        3449259151               NaN
95%             0.00              0.00              0.00       25628284214               NaN
98%             0.00              0.00              0.00       44285675122               NaN
99%             0.00              0.00              0.00       44285675122               NaN
Min             0.00              0.00              0.00            105779                 0
Max             0.00              0.00              0.00       442856751229223372036854776000
```

Cassandra version:

```
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.2 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.

Replication factor 3
4 node cluster
Getting the above message in one node only 
Tried repairing the table but failed with streaming error :

40328:ERROR [StreamReceiveTask:53] 2019-06-10 13:54:33,684 StreamSession.java:593 - [Stream #c9214180-8b82-11e9-90ce-399bac480141] Streaming error occurred on session with peer <IP ADDRESS>
40329-java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to compute ceiling for max when histogram overflowed
40330-  at org.apache.cassandra.utils.Throwables.maybeFail(Throwables.java:51) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
40331-  at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.waitOnFutures(FBUtilities.java:373) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
40332-  at org.apache.cassandra.index.SecondaryIndexManager.buildIndexesBlocking(SecondaryIndexManager.java:383) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
40333-  at org.apache.cassandra.index.SecondaryIndexManager.buildAllIndexesBlocking(SecondaryIndexManager.java:270) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
40334-  at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamReceiveTask$OnCompletionRunnable.run(StreamReceiveTask.java:216) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
40335-  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_144]
40336-  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_144]
40337-  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_144]
40338-  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_144]
--
0354:ERROR [Reference-Reaper:1] 2019-06-10 13:54:33,907 Ref.java:224 - LEAK DETECTED: a reference (org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.Ref$State@7bd8303d) to class org.apache.cassandra.io.util.ChannelProxy$Cleanup@1084465868:PATH/talename-5b621cd0c53311e7a612ffada4e45177/mc-26405-big-Index.db was not released before the reference was garbage collected
```

Table description includes :

```
AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

Any idea why it is happening? Any help or suggestion is welcome.

Comment: This question is a good example of why you should not let your partitions grow too large.

Comment: Thanks Aaron but anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: Pretty much the only path, is to build a new data model (table) with a composite partition key designed to better distribute your data, and reload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have 2 billion cells in a partition. Also having a secondary index on a table with a 44gb partition is going to have issues for multiple reasons. There really isn't much you can do to fix this short of dropping your index and building a new data model to migrate into. You could build a custom version of Cassandra to ignore that exception but something else will come up very soon as you are at the extreme limits of whats even theoretically possible. You are already past a point that I am surprised is running.

If the streaming error is from repairs you can ignore it while you fix your data model. If it's from bootstrapping I think you will need a custom version of Cassandra to stay running in meantime (or can just ignore the down node you are replacing). Keep in mind node failures are a serious threat to you now as bootstrapping likely will not work. When you put so much in a single partition it cannot be scaled out so there are limited options.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Much appreciated..But the best part is table size is 21 GB and partition size is 44 GB :

Comment: Read Count: 2045259100
        Read Latency: 1.8830049956164479 ms
        Write Count: 5975272122
        Write Latency: 0.026771989511911305 ms
        Pending Flushes: 0
                Table: 
                SSTable count: 11
                Space used (live): 21971979508
                Space used (total): 21971979508

Comment: whats compression ratio? Number of keys? If you just put whole tablestats in original question can be more meaningful